# VHDL procedures, BCD to 7seg converter, will this code compile?

Tags: vhdl, fpga

Since I have no possibility to check it out, I would like to ask if this piece of vhdl code compiles.

I made a project at my university and part of it was a BCD to seven segment display converter. I needed it to have four inputs and four outputs (four digits) but back then I didn't have much language knowledge nor experience and I used basically the same piece of code four times within one architecture.

I now want to make it more readable and "professional" so I decided to use a procedure not to repeat the same lines many times. To problem, however, is that I have no possibility to test it.

I searched online for the procedure syntax and improved my code based on new knowledge. Here is how it looks now.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity BCDto7SEGconverter is
port(
sec_j: in std_logic_vector( 3 downto 0 );
sec_d: in std_logic_vector( 3 downto 0 );
min_j: in std_logic_vector( 3 downto 0 );
min_d: in std_logic_vector( 3 downto 0 );
sec_j_7seg: out std_logic_vector( 6 downto 0 );
sec_d_7seg: out std_logic_vector( 6 downto 0 );
min_j_7seg: out std_logic_vector( 6 downto 0 );
min_d_7seg: out std_logic_vector( 6 downto 0 ) );
end BCDto7SEGconverter;

architecture convert of bcdto7SEGconverter is
begin

procedure change(
    signal r_IN  : in  std_logic_vector( 3 downto 0 );
    signal r_OUT : out std_logic_vector( 3 downto 0 )
    ) is
begin
    case r_iN is
        when "0000" => r_OUT <= "1000000";
        when "0001" => r_OUT <= "1111001";
        when "0010" => r_OUT <= "0100100";
        when "0011" => r_OUT <= "0110000";
        when "0100" => r_OUT <= "0011001";
        when "0101" => r_OUT <= "0010010";
        when "0110" => r_OUT <= "0000010";
        when "0111" => r_OUT <= "1111000";
        when "1000" => r_OUT <= "0000000";
        when "1001" => r_OUT <= "0010000";
        when others => r_OUT <= "1111111";
    end case;
end procedure;

begin

process( sec_j, sec_d, min_j, min_d )
begin
    change(sec_j,sec_j_7seg);
    change(sec_d,sec_d_7seg);
    change(min_j,min_j_7seg);
    change(min_d,min_d_7seg);
end process;
end convert;
```

I'm unable to compile this myself so I would like to know whether this code compiles or not.

Comment: No. The procedure specification should be a block declarative item (prior to the architecture begin which is duplicated - remove the first `begin`. In procedure `change` the parameter declaration for `r_Out` should have a constraint of 6 downto 0. These are intended g downto a order for a seven segment display apparently. After those two changes your code analyzes, elaborates and simulates. Matthew Taylor may pop up and tell you where to find a free on-line simulator you can use. Your code doesn't depend on package std_logic_unsigned. Syle guidelines can be used for professional appearance.

Comment: See https://www.edaplayground.com/ for on-line VHDL tools (simulators and synthesis tools, in case Matthew doesn't make a timely appearance). There's an [tag:edaplayground] tag here on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you @user1155120 for corrections and for the links. I managed to work things out.